# Passing a variable through a class Python

Tags: python, function, file, class, error-handling

I am trying to print to pass the `endpoint` variable to the `__init__` function within the `RUN()` class. However it is giving me an error. `AttributeError: module 'configs' has no attribute 'endpoint'`. The endpoint document is saved in the `file1.py` and it is called in `file2.py`. How would I be able to pass endpoint as a param.

file1

```
endpoint = 'hello'
```

file2

```
import file1
class  RUN():
    def __init__(self, endpoint= file1.endpoint):
    
        print("Initialized")

run_websocket = RUN()
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Are the files in the same folder?

Comment: Can you share entire file1.py

Comment: It is better to create a single module called config or cfg to make the module available globally.

Comment: Is it possible that you are using `configs.endpoint` somewhere in your code, or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

The code is absolutely correct. Try deleting the cache of your IDE or build and dist folders, etc. then run again.